# What is the difference in accessing relation directly and using with in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Consider following model

```
class User {
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Roles');
    }
}
```

I can fetch user details as below

```
$user1 = User::find(1);
$user2 = User::with('roles')->find(1);
```

Both the above methods works same. Even without using `with('roles')`, I can still access `roles` of that particular user.

```
echo $user1->roles; // Outputs all the roles of that user
```

So, my question is what is the actual difference/advantage using `with('relation')` ?

Comment: `User::with('roles')->find(1);` when you are using `with` it is called as `EAGER LOADING`. And when you are using `$user1->roles;` is called as `LAZY LOADING`. Refer for more info https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads  and https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `with()` function is used for [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). When loading one user this will have little impact. When you try to get the `roles` property, the query to get the roles for this user is executed, but only for this user.

Now consider loading a list of users from the database. When you call the `roles` property for each of these users, a query will be executed for every user. This is not a good way to work.
When you use the `with()` function, the relations are eager loaded. Wich means Laravel will load all `roles` in one query and assign them to the correct user objects. When you call the `roles` property on the user objects now, the values are already loaded an no extra database query is needed. reducing the amount of queries to 2.